# PostgreSQL - return most common value for all columns in a table

Tags: postgresql

I've got a table with a lot of columns in it and I want to run a query to find the most common value in each column.

Ordinarily for a single column, I'd run something like:

```
SELECT country
FROM users
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Does PostgreSQL have a built in function for doing this or can anyone suggest a query I could run to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with the query?

Comment: @Denis: OP wants to get the mode of each column, instead of just the `country` column.  I'm not sure that's particularly relational, though.

Comment: @Keven: Ah, yes, it's beginning to tick. OP should probably look into window functions. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Another approach would be to use `most_common_vals` from `pg_stats`, once the table is properly analyzed.

Comment: @Kouber: Won't that information age rapidly?  I'm not sure you can do that without creating race conditions.

Comment: Don't think you can achieve it easier with Window functions. You will need at least a count(*)/or `OVER` per column. So it is better to stick to simple and readable SQL. Check my answer

Comment: How should one break ties?

Answer (score 4):

Using the same query, for more than one column you should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT country
    FROM users
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) country
,(
    SELECT city
    FROM users
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) city
```

This works for any type and will return all the values in the same row, with the columns having its original name.

For more columns just had more subquerys as:

```
,(
    SELECT someOtherColumn
    FROM users
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) someOtherColumn
```

**Edit:**

**You could reach it with window functions also. However it will not be better in performance nor in readability.**

Comment: This is much nicer, and closer to what the OP wanted.

Comment: Could you tell me where the use  of these comma seperated sub-queries is documented? I'd like to know more about it.

Comment: The comma separated it's the Cartesian product and I think it belongs to SQL standards. It's basic use of the FROM clause: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html

Answer (score 2):

Starting from PG 9.4 there is aggregate function for this:

```
mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sort_expression)
```

returns the most frequent input value (arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple equally-frequent results)

And for earlier versions, you could create one...

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mode_array(anyarray)
            RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
    SELECT a FROM unnest($1) a GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, 1 LIMIT 1;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;



CREATE AGGREGATE mode(anyelement)(
   SFUNC = array_append, --Function to call for each row. Just builds the array
   STYPE = anyarray,
   FINALFUNC = mode_array, --Function to call after everything has been added to array
   INITCOND = '{}'--Initialize an empty array when starting
) ;
```

Usage: `SELECT mode(column) FROM table;`

Comment: It wasn't clear from this example, but the call to `mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY *sort_expression*)` intentionally has no parameters sent to the `mode` function. e.g. a correct usage of the aggregate function would be `mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col_name DESC) AS most_common_entry`

Comment: @BrDaHa you may want to write to PostgreSQL support, as this is an example from their documentation

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this, I'd write a query like this one:

```
SELECT 'country', country
FROM users
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'city', city
FROM USERS
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
-- etc.
```

It should be noted this only works if all the columns are of compatible types.  If they are not, you'll probably need a different solution.

Comment: Your answer is fine, as you say for having all data in the same column and of the same type, however I don't think that is what was asked

Answer (score 1):

This window function version will read the users table and the computed table once each. The correlated subquery version will read the users table once for each of the columns. If the columns are many as in the OPs case then my guess is that this is faster. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d9edd/2)

```
select distinct on (country_count, age_count) *
from (
    select
        country,
        count(*) over(partition by country) as country_count,
        age,
        count(*) over(partition by age) as age_count
    from users
) s
order by country_count desc, age_count desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Can you provide `EXPLAIN` results to support that assertion?

Comment: @Kevin It is not an _assertion_. It is a _guess_. Will you build the data?

Comment: It just seems to me that the query planner ought to be able to (partially) optimize out the repeated subquery.  I'm just curious whether this is actually the case.  You don't need massive amounts of data to see whether it's doing nested iteration 20 levels deep.